# Speed up Fuzzy Wuzzy by cutting number of comparisons

Tags: python, optimization, fuzzywuzzy

I am currently using Fuzzy Wuzzy string similarity comparison and have code that is working, but am trying to cut down the run time since it takes long. Currently, the code I am using takes each username and compares it to every other username, and then goes to the next and does it again. I am trying to think of a way to get the for loop to skip over comparisons it has already made (which should cut the number of comparisons in half). The subset I am working on currently contains 50,000 rows, so it is doing 2.5 billion comparisons and takes an hour to run. Here is what I have so far:

```
mat1 = []
list1 = df4['usernames'].tolist()

for i in list1:
        mat1.append(process.extract(i, list1, limit= 3))

df4['three_most_similar_usernames'] = mat1
```

Comment: You could try computing the [Soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) of every row. That would need to be done once per row. Once you pre-compute that, you could just run your Fuzzy Wuzzy comparison on rows with identical Soundex codes. Since you're doing an exact match on Soundex, it can benefit from indexes. See here for a Soundex implementation: https://pypi.org/project/Fuzzy/

Comment: If you want to keep the same behavior you can start by replacing FuzzyWuzzy with [RapidFuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz) which provides significantly faster implementations of the same algorithms. It is mostly API compatible, so it should be enough to replace the import with `from rapidfuzz import process`

Comment: Thank you @maxbachmann, I just tried using RapidFuzz on some smaller subsets of the data and it has cut down the run time in half so far.

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely understand the code above (what's process.extract? - I assume it is a function that compares the first argument to each element in the second argument), but I think you want something like this:

```
mat1 = []
list1 = df4['usernames'].tolist()

for i, username in enumerate(list1):
        mat1.append(process.extract(i, list1[i+1:], limit= 3))

df4['three_most_similar_usernames'] = mat1
```

Enumerate lets you iterate over indices (`i`) and the corresponding elements (`username`) simultaneously. Then, list1[i+1:] is a slice of list1, containing all the usernames in list1 that are after `username` - so, those with which the current username has not been compared yet.

Comment: Thank you for the response. process.extract is a part of the fuzzy wuzzy package and compares each string (in this case each username) to the other strings in the column and uses a weighted ratio of multiple string comparisons to give a score of how similar one string is to another. I tried the code you wrote out but it gave "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"